# Wait to for loop finish job

Tags: jquery

I try to make table with code, but something not going well.

I have array in witch i generate code  for part of table:

```
List.push("<tr><td colspan=\"5\">");

for (k = 0; k < finalList.length; k++) {
    List.push(finalList[k]);
}
List.push("</td></tr>");
```

On the end i append it to table like:

```
$("#commentTable tbody").append(List);
```

Lets say that in array `finalList` I have divs with images inside.
for example
images in multiple divs for example :

When i run code and use inspect element code is generated like

```
<tr><td colspan="5"></td></tr>
    <div><img src="1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="2.jpg" /></div>
```

etc...

Like it is work async and working for while it is line `List.push("</td></tr>");` finish.

I hope i was clear. That i can do to resolve this?

Thanx

Comment: what's inside of `finalList`?

Comment: Make working fiddle of this, and than we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, for cycles do not start separate threads.

Why not simplify it and use a simple string?

```
var s = "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">";
for(var k=0; k<finalList.length; k++){
    s += finalList[k];
}
s += "</td></tr>";
```

Or you can even do

```
var s = '<tr><td colspan="5">' + finalList.join('') + '</td></tr>';
```

and then

```
$("#commentTable tbody").append(s);
```

Comment: Thanx, this solution its great, it is help me very much.